# javascript - how to manipulate (nodeList) data from a ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying identify the id of a form's input, however the form is built dynamically and the id's are created automatically.  The goal is to get the id and use an ajax call to check the value of the input.

**original js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // catch the form's submit event
    $('#id_objective_name').keyup(function () {
        // create an AJAX call
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            url: "{% url 'gradebook:validate_objname' %}",
            // on success
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.is_taken == true) {
                    $('#id_objective_name').removeClass('is-valid').addClass('is-invalid');
                    $('#id_objective_name').after('<div class="invalid-feedback d-block" id="usernameError">This username is not available!</div>')
                }
                else {
                    $('#id_username').removeClass('is-invalid').addClass('is-valid');
                    $('#usernameError').remove();

                }

            },
            // on error
            error: function (response) {
                // alert the error if any error occured
                console.log(response.responseJSON.errors)
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
})
```

This code works fine if there is a single form.  However, my page will have several forms with id's such as:

```
#id_objective_set-1-objective_name
#id_objective_set-2-objective_name
#id_objective_set-3-objective_name
...
#id_objective_set-6-objective_name
#id_objective_set-INITIAL_FORMS
#id_objective_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS
#id_objective_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS
#id_objective_set-TOTAL_FORMS
```

I have one workaround in that I'm only interested in the last form generated.  I currently use this and it seems to work, the `(index = (num-5); index < (num-4); ++index)` gets the fifth from last id, which is the last form.

```
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var num = allInputs.length;
    var myID = "";
    for (index = (num-5); index < (num-4); ++index) {
        var myID = allInputs[index].id;
    }
    
$(document).ready(function () {
    // catch the form's submit event
    $('#' + myID).keyup(function () {
        // create an AJAX call
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            url: "{% url 'gradebook:validate_objname' %}",
            .......
```

The part where I'm really unsure about is the `data: $(this).serialize()`.  This sends the data to my backend. However, the backend has no idea on what data to look for.  If it was just a single form, the backend would look for `objective_name`.  But now this data could be anything.  I don't know how to manipulate this data prior to sending it to my backend, I don't even know how to console.log this data. I know very little about ajax so I don't know what's happening with the `get the form data`.  I also couldn't identify a way to manipulate the nodeList `allInputs`.

Comment: First of all, you are not catching the form's submit event, you're catching an <input>'s keyup event. So `$(this)` will refer to the input, not the form. It'll still generate a `name=value` querystring though, which is why the code works. As for the ajax call, it looks like you want to attach it to every form/input. Using consecutively numbered IDs is not necessary, you can use jQuery methods like .find() and .closest() to go down and up the tree. Try not to use any ids, just classes and tags.

Comment: Here's how to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/dukmqar8/